# Отследить изменяемый чекбокс в div и вернуть его id и value

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Есть div с множеством inputoв

```
<div class="content">
 <input type="checkbox" id='1' value='0'/>
 <input type="checkbox" id='2' value='1'/>
 <input type="checkbox" id='3' value='1'/>
 <input type="checkbox" id='4' value='0'/>
</div>
```

Я собираюсь отправить на сервер task_id - ид измененного инпута, и task_value
- его значение.

```
$(".content").click(function(){
    var data = 'task_value='+$('#1').val()+'&task_id='+$('#task_id').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/controllers/send.php',
        type: "POST",
        data:data ,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }});
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно повесить событие на `input`, а не на `div`

```js
$(".content input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    console.log('JS', 'task_value='+this.value + '&task_id='+ this.id);
    console.log('JQ', 'task_value='+$(this).val() + '&task_id='+ $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
 <input type="checkbox" id='1' value='0'/>
 <input type="checkbox" id='2' value='1'/>
 <input type="checkbox" id='3' value='1'/>
 <input type="checkbox" id='4' value='0'/>
</div>
```